# Boto3 S3 client.put_bucket_logging() Broken?

Tags: python, debugging, amazon-s3, boto3

When I call the [client.put_bucket_logging() method](https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_bucket_logging) in boto3 in order to define a location for the log files of a recently created bucket, I receive the following error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (MalformedXML) when calling the 
PutBucketLogging operation: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not 
validate against our published schema
```

[Amazon's documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html) on MalformedXML errors indicates:

> This happens when the user sends malformed xml (xml that doesn't
>   conform to the published xsd) for the configuration. The error message
>   is, "The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate
>   against our published schema."

The documentation for this method is fairly lean, but what does exist doesn't mention anything about passing xml into the arguments. So, I begun to believe this may be a problem with boto3, not the parameters I'm passing into it. I have tried to make adjustments to resolve this problem (reducing only to the required arguments) and double checked my syntax, but cannot find a solution. Anyone else encounter this issue?

EDITS: [REDACTED]
ANSWER: Below

Comment: Could you show how you are actually making the call?  What you are passing in?

Comment: @gamaat... sorry about that. Just added the script to the question.

Comment: The API docs (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTlogging.html) seem to suggest that if you are using a type of CanonicalUser you have to include the ID as well as the DisplayName.

Answer (score 3):

After further investigation, it appears that the [Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.create_bucket) for client.create_bucket() method is missing some key options for the 'ACL' parameter. Specifically, it is missing:

**ACL='log-delivery-write'**

Luckily, the [full set of options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#canned-acl) can be found in a link off the AWS Documentation that @garnaat provided. Thanks for that pointer.

Once I implemented this option for the log bucket, I was able to enable logging for the example bucket using client.put_bucket_logging()

```
kw_args = {
'Bucket': 'example-log-bucket,
    'ACL': 'log-delivery-write'
}
client.create_bucket(**kw_args)

kw_args = {
    'Bucket': 'example-user-bucket,
    'ACL': 'private'
}
client.create_bucket(**kw_args)

kw_args = {
    'Bucket': 'example-user-bucket,
    'BucketLoggingStatus': {
        'LoggingEnabled': {
            'TargetBucket': 'example-log-bucket',
            'TargetPrefix': 'user/'
        }
    }
}
client.put_bucket_logging(**kw_args)
```

Hopefully someone with privileges will get a chance to adjust the boto3 documentation for S3 at some point. It would also be nice to have a heads up in the documentation about [Amazon's three pre-defined groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#specifying-grantee-predefined-groups), since there are a lot of methods which grant permissions to groups.

Answer (score 1):

Per https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/180 --

You could also use:

```
s3c.put_bucket_acl(
    AccessControlPolicy = {
        "Owner": {
            "ID": "canonical_user_id_sdakfjldsakjf" # see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/acct-identifiers.html
        },
        'Grants': [
            {
                'Grantee': {
                    'Type': 'Group',
                    'URI': 'http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/s3/LogDelivery'
                },
                'Permission': 'WRITE'
            },
            {
                'Grantee': {
                    'Type': 'Group',
                    'URI': 'http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/s3/LogDelivery'
                },
                'Permission': 'READ_ACP'
            }
        ]
    },
    Bucket=bucket
)
```

Note Owner is **required** otherwise you will get the MalformedXML error, even though the documentation doesn't currently list it as required in [put_bucket_acl](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_bucket_acl)